How can I enable https requests in a spring boot API?
I configired my spring boot API to receive https requests through a SSL self-signed certificate. When I request via postman its works, but when our frontend application(with SSL certificate too) makes the same request a problem occours.

The API code below:
application.properties
#server port
server.port=5001
        

server.ssl.key-alias=https-example
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:https-example.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-password=xxxxx
server.ssl.enabled=true


SSOApplication
@Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();

        // HTTP Connector
        Connector httpConnector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        httpConnector.setScheme("http");
        httpConnector.setPort(5002); // HTTP port
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpConnector);


        // HTTPS Connector
        Connector httpsConnector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        httpsConnector.setScheme("https");
        httpsConnector.setSecure(true);
        httpsConnector.setPort(443); // HTTPS port
        httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", "src/main/resources/https-example.jks");
        httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "xxxx");
        httpsConnector.setAttribute("keyAlias", "https-example");
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpsConnector);

        return tomcat;
    }


I need help to solve this problem

I think you should not let Spring Boot handle HTTPS traffic.
You should let Nginx/Cloudflare or whatever load balancer do the unpack HTTPS job.
Then pass the HTTP traffic to Spring Boot.

I tried to do this, but the frontend application does't allow any request other than a security request
